# Packaging and installing x509 certificate on client with clickonce app

Tags: wcf

I just got started programming WCF services and got my first service up and running for a local police department. They will be using this to lookup plates for overnight parking violations. It's running message security and an x509 certificate for encryption.

**Is there a way to package the certificate with the installation or some how have the service create it and download it to the client depending on the authentication I am using?**

Right now I am going to be manually installing it on each tough book but would like to automate the process more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certificate distribution is a standard task for most enterprise IT departments, applications modifying CA roots is somewhat taboo.

If you are talking about pushing the public key of a server certificate to each client, look at [Add a trusted root certification authority to a Group Policy object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738131(v=ws.10).aspx).  If you are talking about creating a client certificate for use of mutual TLS authentication, look at [Deploy User Certificates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770857.aspx).

---

If instead you are talking about an ephemeral certificate some other certificate which is only accessed by your application from code, you can add it as an Embedded Resource in your assembly and use it via the [`X509Certificate2(byte[])` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148413(v=vs.110).aspx).

I would caution you against putting a private key in your application resources, since any user of the application can do whatever they wish with it.  PKI is designed such that Private Keys do not need to be shared.  Regardless, [Jeff Valore shows a method to do so](https://codingwithspike.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/embedding-certificates-when-using-wcf-custom-security-tokens/), which I have reproduced below:

```
var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyCert.cer");
var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
var cert = new X509Certificate2(bytes, "certPassword");
```